# getData() returns null, when there is data value in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-intent

I have this in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <data android:scheme="http"/>
  </intent-filter>
```

But when I call:

```
  Intent i = currentActivity.getIntent();
  Log.d("Logging", "i.getAction() is " + i.getCategories());
  Log.d("Logging", "i.getAction() is " + i.getAction());
  Log.d("Logging", "i.getData() is " + i.getData());
  Log.d("Logging", "scheme is " + i.getScheme());
```

I got this back:

```
D/Logging( 5050): i.getAction() is [android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
D/Logging( 5050): i.getAction() is android.intent.action.MAIN
D/Logging( 5050): i.getData() is null
D/Logging( 5050): scheme is null
```

Any thoughts why?

Answer (score 0):

you should try to specify `android:host="somehost.com"` in your data, the scheme alone does not have any meaning and probably gets skipped and ignored, same if you specify url/host without scheme -- these will be ignored as well.